# Incompatible Types in Method

Tags: java

Edit: Initially, parameters were arrays. Arrays could not be converted to doubles. Seems to be working fine since I changed my array parameters to double. This code is solved.

```
// private instance variables
private double myRangeMeters, myRangeFeet, myInitialVel, myRadians;

Catapult(double initialVel, double radians)
{
    myRangeMeters = 0.0;
    myRangeFeet = 0.0;
    myInitialVel = initialVel;
    myRadians = radians;
}

public void calcProjectileDist()
{
    myRangeMeters = (Math.pow(myInitialVel, 2) * Math.sin(2 * myRadians)) / 9.8;
}

public void convertMetersToFeet()
{
    myRangeFeet = myRangeMeters * 3.28084;
}

public double getProjectileDist()
{
    return myRangeFeet;
}
```

Comment: Plus one (+1) for British English

Comment: Hmm? Where do you see British English?

Comment: Mmm, nowhere since the edits.  Seems someone's scarpered off with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with this code

```
Math.pow(myInitialVel, 2)
```

`Math.pow` expects a double not an array.

I can not tell from this code, whether the variables should be changed to `doubles` or whether you should select an index of the array and convert to a double

Comment: Not me. I see why, but the thing is, I'm trying to process an excessive amount of ints (doubles now), but I'm not going to make 42 lines of invoking a method with just different numbers.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: My program is to calculate the distance of an object to be catapulted for six launch angles and seven launch speeds, and to store the results in a two-dimensional array. So, given the six angles and seven velocities, it would require 42 parameters of the same object or 42 variables invoked to a method if I were to give parameters to a method and get rid of the custom constructor completely. Is there an easier way to do this using arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the formula to calculate projectile distance and `pow` and `sin` functions expect value in double.

```
(Math.pow(speed,2) * Math.sin(angle * 2))/9.8
```

As you have an array of initial value and radians so you should loop through each elements then distances in another array

```
public void calcProjectileDist()
    {
        double [] rangeMeters=new double[myInitialVel.length];
        for(int i =0; i<myInitialVel.length;i++){
            rangeMeters[i]=(Math.pow(myInitialVel[i], 2) * Math.sin(2 * myRadians[i])) / 9.8;
        }
    }
```